# Exibir data do MySQL em campo date

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma página de cadastro de cliente com um campo para data de nascimento. Eu consigo escolher uma data e salvá-la no banco de dados. Porém quando eu volto para a tela de cadastro desse cliente esse campo (`type="date"`) não está exibindo o valor salvo no banco de dados. Alguém consegue me ajudar a entender o que tem errado no meu código ?

```
<? $dtnascimento = '';
if($rst[0]['datanascimento'] != '') {
   $dtnascimento = $rst[0]['datanascimento'];
   $dtnascimento = date_format(date_create($dtnascimento),"d/m/Y");
} ?>
```

```html
<label>Data de Nascimento</label>
<input type="date" id="datansc" name="datansc" value="<? echo $dtnascimento ;?>"/>
```

Comment: Quando você da o die $dtnascimento ele retorna a data como?

Comment: a data de nascimento do cliente no formato que eu escolhi `"d/m/Y" `15/02/1975

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente formatar a data para `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Esse é o formato aceito pelo HTML5.

Caso você realmente precise modificar ou mascarar a data tente visualizar esse tópico:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978631/how-to-set-date-format-in-html-date-input-tag

```html
<div>
Note que ele despreza a data:
<input type="date" id="datansc" name="datansc" value="15/02/1975"/>
</div>

<div>
Note que agora ele exibe o valor:
<input type="date" id="datansc" name="datansc" value="1975-02-15"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo ! Tks

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa usar é isso aqui:

```
<?= date_format(new DateTime($dtnascimento),'d/m/Y') ?>
```

e só funciona com o tipo date se não me engano, se estiver datetime no banco de dados ou no seu html, tem que editar, mas não fica legal, tipo:

```
<?= date_format(new DateTime($dtnascimento),'d/m/Y H:i:s') ?>
```